# Не могу понять ошибку

Tags: c++, visual-c++

В чём ошибка?

```
// Lab_num_five_chast_2.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "locale"
#include "conio.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "cmath"
#include "stdarg.h"

using namespace std;

int MyFunc(int x, ...)
{
    int y, chisl, znam;

    znam = pow(x, 3) - (0.8 * x) - 0.75;
    if (znam != 0)
    {
        chisl = 7.3 * pow(x, 3) + (tan(x) * 1 / 5);
        y = chisl / znam;
    }
    return y;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "Russina");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    
    int x, const с = 5;

    cout << "Введённое число пользователем" << endl;
    cout << "Введите x: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Ответ: " <<MyFunc(x, 0) << endl;
    cout << "Число с константой" << endl;
    cout << "Const = 5" << endl << "Ответ: " << MyFunc(с, 0) << endl;
    cout << "Многократный вызов функции" << endl;
    cout << "Функция с пятью параметров  = " << MyFunc(12, 13, 1, 23, 44, 0);
    cout << "Функция с десятью праметров = " << MyFunc(10, 22, 133, 44, 55, 4, 1, 43, 24, 0);
    cout << "Функция с двенадцатью параметров = " << MyFunc(1, 2, 33, 424, 55, 11, 12, 13, 40, 22, 223, 33, 0);
    _getch();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот условие

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приведение к целому - `znam` таки ноль.

```
double chisl;
double znam = ...;
```

Ну и инициализировать `y = 0;` на тот случай, если в `if` мы все-таки не попадем, что маловероятно при целом `х`.

Comment: Сделал y = 0, ошибка исчезла спасибо.

Comment: @JZ_52 - галочка слева - щёлк :)

Comment: @JZ_52 и Вы же понимаете, что с целыми `y, chisl, znam` результат будет неправильным?

Comment: Потому что там есть не целые числа? Ну да, ты прав, я исправлю программу.